# WooCommerce show a variation both in check boxes and in a list

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I think this is more a theoretical question, because I cannot find anyone online who has did this before.

Our customer is selling gravel and sand in bags and in bulk with the truck.

So I have the following attributes:

**Quantity**: 0,5 m³, 0,7 m³ and 1 m³ (3 options)

**Quantity bulk**: 10 ton, 11 ton, 12 ton ---- (a list to 35 ton, 25 options total)

**Size**: 8 - 16 mm, 14 - 20 mm (etc. 5 options)

As you can see, I want to combine the **Quantity** and the **Quantity bulk** variations..... but I do I want to display them differently in the frontend. The bulk options in a list, and the quantity options as checkboxes.

See a visual here:

[image: size-quantity-design]

I want to display them on my website just like I listed them, however the **Quantity** and the **Quantity bulk** options belong to each other, so I cannot create them as separated attributes in WooCommerce. This is because you do not combine all three attributes with each other. (so, no Size, Quantity **and** Quantity bulk product exists)

I hope I am clear at this point.

So how would you guys handle this? I have already created them as separate attributes, but that is a no go because you are overcomplete with one attribute in WooCommerce.

Answer (score 1):

**This problem only looks complex, it's not easy either**. I'm working on similiar solution now.

**WooCommerce doesn't support hierarchical attributes**. You can't define quantity attribute as parent of volume (m3) and weight (XX tons) options. I wouldn't separate them - **logically this is one attribute** (and size is second). **Drawback: there will be a lot of variants** (5 * 28) - **you have to define prices for all of them!**

**On front** we have **two select fields** in standard theme. 
Modyfying size parameter is simple - replace select with radio buttons (with jQuery).
**Quantity parameter select can be replaced with more elements** - radio buttons for volume options and select for rest (weights). **Choosing any of these options should update form value of original (now hidden) quantity select**.

After this we have two attributes (both have to be choosen): size (granularity) and 'kind of quantity'. I wrote 'kind of quantity' because beside attribute selects we have original quantity input. **This way we can order f.e. 2 bags (quantity input) x "0,7 m3 minibags, 8-16mm" (variant of 2 attributes)**.

It **can be sufficient** (standard) solution for many cases ... **but this way we have an option to order only one kind of quantity at one time**. This is good for cart, adding the same variants we're getting one line with updated quantity.

Looking at image you need **something more usable** - 'quantity multiplier' for each 'kind of quantity' (checkboxes for volumes + select for weights). It can be achiewed with more JS on frontend (array of quaintities for choosen quantity kinds) and filters on backend (woocommerce_add_cart_item_data, woocommerce_before_calculate_totals ...). **It could have drawbacks, too!** - f.e. one cart item of set (1x0,5m3 + 2x0,7m3 + 12ton) - **adjusting quantity in cart we're changing amount of sets, not individual quantities**.

**Using filters we have possibility to almost freely adjust all prices and delivering costs**. This way **we don't have to define all variant's prices** - we can calculate them from needed volume and/or weight! **In practice this is only one price (per 1000kg) for each of granularity variants** - volume prices can be calculated from weight. Bulk quantities **select** (25 options) **can be replaced with single numerical input** (minimum 10[t]) and unit **price corelated with ordered quantity** (cheaper for greater orders). The same (parametrized) **calculations can be done for delivering costs** (kind and quantity of trucks, distance).

As optimal (usability, UX) **I would create complex frontend** (product page) allowing mixed amounts of 'kinds of quantities' **but added to cart as separated items** (lines) for better manipulations (quantity adjustments) and readability.